# how to assign value to entity got from database

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a linq query like below:

```
public IQueryable<vmEmp> GetEmp(int crewid)
    {
        var dt = new EmpEntities();
        var e = from t in dt.tblEmp
                where (t.CrewId == crewid)
                select new vmEmp
                {
                    Id = -1,
                    Crew = t.crewid,
                    Name = t.Name,
                    Address = t.Address
                };
        return e;
        }
```

I hope can make the Id auto decrease by 1 till end of the employee.
like first's Id is -1, second's is -2, third is -3 ...

How to do that here? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a counter variable and decrease it for every record while you project it to your custom POCO.

```
public IQueryable<vmEmp> GetEmp(int crewid)
{
    int counter=0;
    var dt = new EmpEntities();

    //load the items to a list of anonymous type
    var eList = from t in dt.tblEmp
            where (t.CrewId == crewid)
            .Select(s=>
              new  { Id = 0,
                     Crew = s.crewid,
                     Name = s.Name,
                     Address = s.Address
                  }).ToList();

    var e=eList.Select(x=> new vmEmp
            {
                Id = --counter,
                Crew = x.Crew,
                Name = x.Name,
                Address = x.Address
            });
    return e.AsQueryable();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but got error "An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator "

Comment: This pulls complete `tblEmp` into memory in stead of only the required fields. Another point, maybe a matter of taste, is that it's not recommended to use LINQ functions with side effects (i.e. affecting an external variable).

Answer (score 2):

If this was LINQ-to-objects, you could use [this overload of `Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534638%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var dt = new EmpEntities();
var e = dt.tblEmp
        .Where(t => t.CrewId == crewid)
        .Select((t,index) => new vmEmp
        {
            Id = -index - 1,
            Crew = t.crewid,
            Name = t.Name,
            Address = t.Address
        });
```

But EF doesn't suport this, because the indexer can't be translated into SQL. So you need a work-around:

```
var dt = new EmpEntities();
var e = dt.tblEmp
        .Where(t => t.CrewId == crewid)
        .Select(t => new 
        {
            Id = 0,
            Crew = t.crewid,
            Name = t.Name,
            Address = t.Address
        }
        .AsEnumerable() // Continue in memory
        .Select((t,index) => new vmEmp
        {
            Id = -index - 1,
            Crew = t.Crew,
            Name = t.Name,
            Address = t.Address
        });
```

Side note: it's recommended to put `dt` in a `using` construct.